# Does process close itself?

Tags: c#, process

**Edit: I am running `netsh` with args (e.g. wlan show network).**

```
public static string Run(string cmd, string args = null) {
    var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = cmd;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    process.Start();
    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();

    return output;
}
```

Does process close itself?

[image]
I am afraid of these Console Window Hosts, that they are no closed processes.

Comment: Why would a process close itself? Some programs run for on operation and quit, but there is no way to say for "a process" how it is going to behave. Usually one would know if they select what process to start (like "ping" would quit quickly, "notepad" would not quit at all) so such philosophical questions is rarely arise in real scenarios. And in extreme case you are talking about [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) that has no solution... So consider to [edit] question to narrow down what you are asking.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I edited the question.